# iPhone UIView animation

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Grettings to you...

i want to paginate when the user swipe on the left or right side of the uiview

i am able to detect the swipes using UISwipeGestureRecognizer.

now what i am trying to do is when the user is swiping i want to give slide animation.

currently i have the below code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft, forView:[self cardView] cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
```

this gives me the flip effect when i swipe on the view.

Please provide me some example or links to try the slide effect when swipe on the view.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use a `UIScrollView`, not a straight `UIView`. This has support for swipes and paging. Here's a [nice tutorial](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/3393-uiscrollview-tutorial.html) to get you started. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the reply.now what i like to know is how can i implement slide effect when swiping

Comment: If I'm understanding you right, I think that this project gives an example of the slide animation: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/05/22/iphone-uiscrollview-with-paging-example/

Comment: i have found this code CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
 [animation setDelegate:self];
 [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
 [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
 [animation setDuration:.5f]; //1.0f was original
 [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
 
 [self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
 [[self.view layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:kAnimationKey];    and getting the following error error: 'kAnimationKey' undeclared (first use in this function)..any help pls

Comment: add #define kAnimationKey @"animationKey" to the top of your header file. It's just the name of some animation, doesn't really matter. Or, replace kAnimationKey in that code with some NSString.